# Why is $w^{(n+1)} = (n+1)!$?

Tags: calculus

Why is $w^{(n+1)} = (n+1)!$ where $w = \prod_{i=0}^{n} (x-x_i)$? Note that $x_i$ are constants. That is, why is $\frac{d^{n+1}}{d^{n+1}x} w = (n+1)!$. I have tried to derive the result myself but simply got too overwhelmed by the many terms(+ I am not a master of derivatives).

Answer (score 2):

We have that by $n+1$ derivations only the $x^{n+1}$ term suvives, that is

$$w = \prod_{i=0}^{n} (x-x_i)=x^{n+1}+\ldots \implies \frac{d}{dx} w= (n+1)x^{n}+\ldots \implies \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} w=(n+1)!$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint - when you multiply out the right hand side you will have a polynomial of degree $n+1$ with leading power of $x$ being $x^{n+1}$.  All other terms have lower powers.  So when you differentiate $n+1$ times, what are you left with?

Comment: I would think that we are then left with the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$? But that does not steer me towards a sensible result I think :/

Comment: Ahh, no, just looked up the definitions again. Thanks! I get it now :)

Comment: Great, you are welcome.